# Filter out and add up

Tags: code-golf, string, number

#### Task

The task is very simple. Given a non-empty string containing **numbers**, **uppercase** and **lowercase letters**, output the sum of the remaining numbers. For example:

```
a1wAD5qw45REs5Fw4eRQR33wqe4WE
```

Filtering out all the letters would result into:

```
 1   5  45   5  4    33   4
```

The sum of these numbers is `1 + 5 + 45 + 5 + 4 + 33 + 4 = 97`. So the output would be `97`.

#### Test Cases

```
a > 0
0 > 0
5 > 5
10 > 10
a0A > 0
1a1 > 2
11a1 > 12
4dasQWE65asAs5dAa5dWD > 79
a1wAD5qw45REs5Fw4eRQR33wqe4WE > 97
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the submission with the least amount of bytes wins!

Comment: I knew I had written that Labyrinth program before... [here is the same challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/730/8478) but with negative numbers as well (which makes a surprisingly big difference for some languages, so I don't think they're dupes).

Comment: @MartinBüttner Looks like that one doesn't include negative numbers: "-n (where n is an integer) is not counted as a negative n, but as a hyphen followed by n."

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. You're saying it has hyphens and this one doesn't.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## GS2, 2 bytes

```
Wd
```

[Try it online!](http://gs2.tryitonline.net/#code=V2Q&input=YTF3QUQ1cXc0NVJFczVGdzRlUlFSMzN3cWU0V0U)

#### How it works

```
W     Read all numbers.
      For input x, this executes map(int, re.findall(r'-?\d+', x)) internally.
 d    Compute their sum.
```

Comment: Well, this was unexpected...

Comment: @Adnan: It's Dennis. Given enough time he can find a solution to any code golf in less than 4 bytes.

Answer (score 13):

### [Labyrinth](https://github.com/mbuettner/labyrinth), 8 bytes

Take that, Pyth...

```
?+
;,;!@
```

[Try it online!](http://labyrinth.tryitonline.net/#code=PysKOyw7IUA&input=YTF3QUQ1cXc0NVJFczVGdzRlUlFSMzN3cWU0V0U)

#### Explanation

The usual primer (stolen from Sp3000):

- Labyrinth is 2D and stack-based. Stacks have an infinite number of zeroes on the bottom.
- When the instruction pointer reaches a junction, it checks the top of the stack to determine where to turn next. Negative is left, zero is forward and positive is right.

What comes in really handy here is that Labyrinth has two different input commands, `,` and `?`. The former reads a single byte from STDIN, or `-1` at EOF. The latter reads an integer from STDIN. It does so skipping everything that *isn't* a number and then reads the first decimal number it finds. This one returns `0` at EOF, so we can't use it to check for EOF reliably here.

The main loop of the program is this compact bit:

```
?+
;,
```

With `?` we read an integer (ignoring all letters), with `+` we add it to the running total (which starts out as one of the implicit zeroes at the stack bottom). Then we read another character with `,` to check for EOF. As long as we're not at EOF, the read character will be a letter which has a positive character code, so the IP turns right (from its point of view; i.e. west). `;` discards the character because we don't need it and then we enter the loop again.

Once we're at EOF, `,` pushes a `-1` so the IP turns left (east) instead. `;` again discards that `-1`, `!` prints the running total as an integer and `@` terminates the program.

Comment: Awesome stuff Martin!

Answer (score 7):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 8 bytes

```
1Y4XXXUs
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=MVk0WFhYVXM&input=JzRkYXNRV0U2NWFzQXM1ZEFhNWRXRCc)

```
1Y4      % predefined literal: '\d+'
XX       % implicit input. Match regular expression. Returns a cell array of strings
         % representing numbers
XU       % convert each string to a double. Returns a numeric array
s        % sum of numeric array
```

Answer (score 6):

### CJam, 13 bytes

Fixed to work with input without numbers thanks to Dennis! Also saved a byte by replacing the letters array with an array of ASCII above code point 64. And then another byte saved by Dennis!

```
q_A,s-Ser~]1b
```

Simple transliteration from letters to spaces, then eval and sum. [Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q_A%2Cs-Ser%7E%5D1b&input=a3bv6).

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript ES6, 35 bytes

```
s=>eval(s.replace(/\D+/g,'+')+'.0')
```

#### How it works

First, we replace each string of non-digits with `"+"`. There are basically four different ways that this could end up:

```
1. 1b23c456   => 1+23+456
2. a1b23c456  => +1+23+456
3. 1b23c456d  => 1+23+456+
4. a1b23c456d => +1+23+456+
```

Cases 1 and 2 are taken care of already. But we somehow need to fix the last `+` so that it doesn't cause an error. We could remove it with `.replace(/\+$,"")`, but that's too expensive. We could append a `0` to the end, but that would affect the last number if the string does not end with a `+`. A compromise is to append `.0`, which is both a valid number on its own and doesn't affect the value of other integers.

Here's a few other values that would work as well:

```
.0
-0
 +0
-""
-[]
0/10
0e-1
.1-.1
```

#### Alternate version, also 35 bytes

```
s=>s.replace(/\d+/g,d=>t+=+d,t=0)|t
```

#### Another alternate version, 36 bytes

```
s=>s.split(/\D/).map(d=>t+=+d,t=0)|t
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina), <del>22</del> 11

```
\d+
$0$*1
1
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=XGQrCiQwJCoxCjE&input=YTF3QUQ1cXc0NVJFczVGdzRlUlFSMzN3cWU0V0U)

11 bytes (!) saved thanks to Martin!

Basically just decimal to unary then count the `1`s.

Comment: I should probably make `$0` implicit if a substitution starts with `$*`. It's a very common pattern and that would have let you beat Pyth. ;)

Comment: @MartinBüttner While you're at it you could make the right character default to something too :O

Comment: hm, not a bad idea. I'll think about it.

Answer (score 5):

## Japt, 2 bytes

```
Nx
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=Tng=&input=YTF3QUQ1cXc0NVJFczVGdzRlUlFSMzN3cWU0V0U=)

#### How it works

```
N    // Implicit: N = (parse input for numbers, "strings", and [arrays])
x    // Sum. Implicit output.
```

Comment: I'm getting an error "Japt.stdout" must be sent to an HTMLElement

Comment: @Downgoat This happens occasionally; I'm not sure why. Reloading the page seems to fix this.

Answer (score 4):

### Pyth, <s>12</s> <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
ssM:z"\D"3
```

```
    z        autoinitialized to input()
   : "\D"3   split on non-digits
 sM          convert all elements of resulting array to ints
s            sum
```

Fortunately, `s` (convert to int) returns `0` when applied to the empty string, so I don't have to worry about the fact that `split("a1b", "\D+")` returns `["", "1", ""]`. Similarly, `split("a", "\D+")` returns `["", ""]`.

This even allows me to split on every non-digit individually, since `1 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 2` is the same thing as `1 + 2`.

Thanks to [Thomas Kwa](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/39328/thomas-kwa) for a byte!

Answer (score 4):

## [Gol><>](https://golfish.herokuapp.com/), 4 bytes

```
iEh+
```

So short I need dummy text...

Comment: Perhaps you should explain your code with your extra space :)

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), 18 bytes

```perl6
{[+] .comb(/\d+/)}
{[+] .split(/\D/)}
```

#### Usage:

```perl6
my &code = {[+] .comb(/\d+/)}

say code 'a'; # 0
say code '0'; # 0
say code '5'; # 5
say code '10'; # 10
say code 'a0A'; # 0
say code '1a1'; # 2
say code '11a1'; # 12
say code '4dasQWE65asAs5dAa5dWD'; # 79
say code 'a1wAD5qw45REs5Fw4eRQR33wqe4WE'; # 97
```

Comment: Saves a byte to use a whatevercode block: `*.comb(/\d+/).sum`

Comment: @Steffan I believe that may have been before the `.sum` method was added to the language. Which if I recall correctly would make it unavailable according to the rules.

Comment: That rule has changed since, you can now use languages newer than the challenge. I didn't know that Raku never had a sum method though

Comment: @Steffan. Originally Raku did not have `sum` of any sort. Partially because `sum(1..5)` could be written using the reduce meta operator `[+](1..5)`. At some point it became obvious that there could be an optimization if the input was a range. A range could calculate its sum without going over its contents. So now the meta operator `[+]...` gets converted to `sum` which will allow for this optimization to take place. Basically the only reason `sum` was added is as an optimization. https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/commit/6d970110df1c9fc160833137c66d8394b8b9b328

Answer (score 3):

## Jelly, 6 bytes

```
&-ṣ-ḌS
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=Ji3huaMt4biMUw&input=&args=ImExd0FENXF3NDVSRXM1Rnc0ZVJRUjMzd3FlNFdFIg)

#### How it works

```
&-ṣ-ḌS  Main link. Input: L (string)

&-      Take the bitwise AND of L's characters and -1.
        This attempts to cast to int, so '0' & -1 -> 0 & -1 -> 0.
        On failure, it returns the integer argument (if any), so 'a' & -1 -> -1.
  ṣ-    Split the resulting list at occurrences of -1.
    Ḍ   Convert each chunk from decimal to integer. In particular, [] -> 0.
     S  Compute the sum of the results.
```

Answer (score 3):

## Perl, 21 + 1 = 22 bytes

```
$_=eval join"+",/\d+/g
```

Requires the `-p` flag:

```
$ perl -pe'$_=eval join"+",/\d+/g' <<< 'a1wAD5qw45REs5Fw4eRQR33wqe4WE'
97
```

Comment: Does this work when there aren't any numbers? e.g. `a`?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Good question, I guess it will print nothing which in a numeric context is `0` ;-)

Answer (score 3):

## Julia, 35 bytes

```
s->sum(parse,matchall(r"\d+","0"s))
```

This is an anonymous function that accepts a string and returns an integer. To call it, assign it to a variable.

We use `matchall` to get an array consisting of matches of the regular expression `\d+`, which are just the integers in the string. We have to tack on a 0 to the front of the string, otherwise for cases like `"a"`, we'd be summing over an empty array, which causes an error. We then apply `parse` to each string match, which converts to integers, and take the sum.

Comment: `parse` can become `int` if you don't mind the deprecation warning.

Comment: @Dennis I do though ._.

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 4 bytes

```
⁽±Ḋ⌊
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJQcyIsIiIsIuKBvcKx4biK4oyKIiwiIiwiNGRhc1FXRTY1YXNBczVkQWE1ZFdEICJd)

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-n`, 23 bytes

Based on [Ventero’s answer here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/742/11261).

```ruby
p eval$_.scan(/\d+/)*?+
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpclm0km6eUuyCpaUlaboW2wsUUssSc1Ti9YqTE_M09GNStPU1tey1IbJQRQv2JhqWO7qYFpabmAa5Fpu6lZukBgUGGRuXF6aahLtCFAEA)

Comment: [alternative 23 you might enjoy](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpclm0km6eUuyCpaUlaboW2wsUUssScxTSi0uTNPRjXPR17LU1te0NILJQRQtueiZyGXCZchkacCUaOHIZJhpyGYIIk5TE4sBwVzPTxGLHYtMUx0TTlHAXrkTDckcX08JyE9Mg12JTt3KT1KDAIGPj8sJUk3BXiIkA)

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript, <s>32</s> 39 bytes

```
s=>eval((s.match(/\d+/g)||[0]).join`+`)
```

```js
f=
s=>eval((s.match(/\d+/g)||[0]).join`+`)

F=s=>document.body.innerHTML+='<pre>f(\''+s+'\') -> '+f(s)+'\n</pre>'

F('a')
F('5')
F('10')
F('1a1')
F('11a1')
F('4dasQWE65asAs5dAa5dWD')
F('a1wAD5qw45REs5Fw4eRQR33wqe4WE')
```

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 51 bytes

```
Total@ToExpression@StringCases[#,DigitCharacter..]&
```

Catching the wrong end of the verbose Mathematica builtins. 1 Byte off with the help of @DavidC

Comment: `DigitCharacter ..` will save 1 byte

Comment: `DigitCharacter` doesn't work as written because it removes all the digits whereas we want to remove all the letters...

Comment: you are right.  I was thinking of `Total@ ToExpression@StringCases[#, DigitCharacter ..] &`

Comment: I see! Yeah that change saves a byte.

Comment: 48 bytes by replacing `Total` with `Tr`

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 64 bytes

```
<?php preg_match_all("/\d+/",$argv[1],$a);echo array_sum($a[0]);
```

Run it as

```
php -f filterOutAndAddUp.php <test_case>
```

https://eval.in/517817

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles and Stack Exchange. This is a great answer (+1), however it could be improved by adding a code explanation and breakdown. Also, could you use `<?` instead of `<?php`?

Answer (score 2):

## R, <s>46</s> 43 bytes

```
sum(strtoi(strsplit(scan(,''),'\\D')[[1]]))
```

**Explanation**

```
                    scan(,'')                  # Take the input string
           strsplit(         ,'\\D')           # Returns list of all numeric parts of the string
                                    [[1]]      # Unlists to character vector
    strtoi(                              )     # Converts to numeric vector
sum(                                      )    # Sums the numbers
```

**Sample run**

```
> sum(strtoi(strsplit(scan(,''),'\\D')[[1]]))
1: a1wAD5qw45REs5Fw4eRQR33wqe4WE
2: 
Read 1 item
[1] 97
```

Edit: Replaced `[^0-9]` with `\\D`.

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles and Code Golf. This is a great first answer; however it would be improved by adding a code explanation and breakdown, so we know how it works.

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org) + `math.unicode sorting.human`, 36 bytes

```factor
[ find-numbers [ real? ] filter Σ ]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=JYq7asNAEEX7-Yop0lposdaEpAgCyyZNwApGhXEx0Y5igbXSvlhMyEe4TiMIzuek99_koebewz3346uh2vd2vJ63z49P6zvsyB_QsQmsa3boeutb_ZocQkf6XyZBt3WvGAfL3p8G22qPJuI9mPgGBClIEClQmoMgAeIvMkVuUxULSS53UuUkVbUEEjFfShMzWRZOrmLG5aacz6PhrCrg_RJ8M7u93uywabWa6dC9sHW4Q8t0fMD973z0bPH7E_fT99LRgMnE4zj1Dw)

```
                  ! "11a1"
find-numbers      ! { "" 11 "a" 1 }
[ real? ] filter  ! { 11 1 }
Σ                 ! 12
```

Answer (score 1):

### PowerShell, <s>28</s> 26 bytes

```
$args-replace"\D",'+0'|iex
```

Takes input `$args` then does a regex `-replace` to swap the letters with `+0`, then pipes that to `iex` (short for `Invoke-Expression` and similar to `eval`).

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\filter-out-and-add-up.ps1 'a1wAD5qw45REs5Fw4eRQR33wqe4WE'
97
```

---

**Alternatively**

If you're OK with some extraneous output, you can do the following, also at <s>28</s> 26 bytes:

```
$args-split"\D"|measure -s
```

This will take the input string `$args` and `-split` it into an array-of-strings on the non-numbers (removing them in the process). For example, `1a2b33` would turn into `['1','2','33']`. We pipe that to `Measure-Object` with the `-Sum` parameter. Output would be like the below:

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\filter-out-and-add-up.ps1 'a1wAD5qw45REs5Fw4eRQR33wqe4WE'

Count    : 21
Average  : 
Sum      : 97
Maximum  : 
Minimum  : 
Property :
```

<sub>Edit -- durr, don't need the `[ ]` in the regex since I'm no longer specifying a list of possible matches ...</sub>

Answer (score 1):

## Gema, 39 characters

```
<D>=@set{s;@add{${s;};$0}}
?=
\Z=${s;0}
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ gema '<D>=@set{s;@add{${s;};$0}};?=;\Z=${s;0}' <<< 'a1wAD5qw45REs5Fw4eRQR33wqe4WE'
```

Answer (score 1):

### Seriously, 13 bytes

```
,ú;û+@s`≈`MΣl
```

[Try it online!](http://seriously.tryitonline.net/#code=LMO6O8O7K0BzYOKJiGBNzqNs&input=ImExd0FENXF3NDVSRXM1Rnc0ZVJRUjMzd3FlNFdFIg)

Explanation:

```
,ú;û+@s`≈`MΣl
,              push input
 ú;û+          push "abc...zABC...Z" (uppercase and lowercase English letters)
     @s        split on letters
       `≈`M    convert to ints
           Σ   sum
            l  length (does nothing to an integer, pushes 0 if an empty list is left, in the case where the string is all letters)
```

Comment: @Adnan Good catch - it outputs the empty list with `a`. Should be a one-byte fix.

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 70 bytes

```
s->{int n=0;for(String i:s.split("\\D+"))n+=Long.valueOf(i);return n;}
```

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, 106 bytes

Works on TI-83/84 calculators!

```
Input Str1
"{0,→Str2
Str1+"N0→Str1
For(I,1,length(Ans
sub(Str1,I,1
If inString("0123456789",Ans
Then
Str2+Ans→Str2
Else
If ","≠sub(Str2,length(Str2),1
Str2+","→Str2
End
End
sum(expr(Ans
```

Answer (score 1):

## Clojure/ClojureScript, 35 bytes

```
#(apply +(map int(re-seq #"\d+"%)))
```

Answer (score 1):

## Bash + GNU utilities, 29

```
grep -Eo [0-9]+|paste -sd+|bc
```

---

If it is required to support input with no numbers (e.g. `a`), then we can do this:

## Bash + GNU utilities, 38

1 byte saved thanks to @TobySpeight.

```
(grep -Eo [0-9]+;echo 0)|paste -sd+|bc
```

Comment: This prints nothing for input `a`. [We are currently discussing](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/8395) whether that's valid or not.

Comment: @Dennis.  Ok.  I added another version to cover both eventualities.

Comment: You could use `;` instead of `||` to always add zero, for no harm.

Comment: @TobySpeight Yes, thats good - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## R, 50 bytes

Requires having `gsubfn` installed

```
sum(gsubfn::strapply(scan(,''),'\\d+',strtoi)[[1]])
```

Uses `strtoi` to coerce to numeric

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby 45 bytes

```
$*[0].split(/[a-z]/i).map(&:to_i).inject 0,:+
```

(First attempt at work, will revisit this)

Answer (score 1):

## POSIX sh + tr + dc, <strike>27</strike> 25 bytes

```
dc -e "0d`tr -sc 0-9 +`p"
```

Converts any run of non-digits (including the terminating newline) to `+` operator, pushes two zeros onto the stack (in case input begins with non-digit), adds them all and prints the result.  There may be an extra zero remaining at bottom of stack, but we don't care about that.

Answer (score 1):

### Lua, 51 Bytes

Pretty short for once! Even shorter than Java! The input must be a command-line argument for it to work.

```lua
a=0 arg[1]:gsub("%d+",function(c)a=a+c end)print(a)
```

#### Ungolfed

```lua
a=0                 -- Initialize the sum at 0
arg[1]:gsub("%d+",  -- capture each group of digits in the string
  function(c)       -- and apply an anonymous function to each of them
  a=a+c             -- sums a with the latest group captured
end)               
print(a)            -- output a
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 70 bytes

I am putting a Python answer just for fun.

```
import re
j=0
for i in map(int,re.findall('\d+',input())):j+=i
print j
```

Very simple and uses regex to find all the numbers in the input. [Try it online!](http://ideone.com/axFm6W)

Comment: In this context you have to use `raw_input` or switch to python3. A smaller version (py3, 56 bytes) :  `import re;print(sum(map(int,re.findall('\d+',input()))))`.

Answer (score 1):

## Oracle SQL 11.2, 105 bytes

```
SELECT NVL(SUM(TO_NUMBER(COLUMN_VALUE)),0)FROM XMLTABLE(('"'||regexp_replace(:1,'[a-zA-Z]','","')||'"'));
```

The regex convert alpha characters to ','

XMLTABLE create one row per item in the string using ',' as the separator.

SUM the rows to get the result.

NVL is needed to account for a string with no digit.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 71 bytes

I just had to make one-liner, though it costs a whole byte more than @TanMath's answer

```
sum(map(int,"".join([i*i.isdigit()or" "for i in raw_input()]).split()))
```

Explaination:

```
raw_input()                             - Input
"".join([i*i.isdigit()or" "for i in _]) - Replace non-digits with spaces 
map(int, _.split())                     - Split on spaces, and convert to number
sum(_)                                  - Sum the resulting list
```

Answer (score 1):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 19 bytes

```
~:scan&/\d+/|:sum+Z
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBIjfbpaUlaboWm-usipMT89T0Y1K09WusiktztaMgMjdVChTcopUSDcsdXUwLy01Mg1yLTd3KTVKDAoOMjcsLU03CXZViIWoXLIDQAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v2.0a0 [`-x`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 3 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

'Cause ETH's solution is a bit cheaty!

```
q\D
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&flags=LXg&code=cVxE&input=ImExd0FENXF3NDVSRXM1Rnc0ZVJRUjMzd3FlNFdFIg)

```
q\D     :Implicit input of string
q       :Split on
 \D     :  RegEx /\D/ (or /[^0-9]/)
        :Implicit output of sum of resulting array
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 6 bytes

```
$+a@XI
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCIkK2FAWEkiLCIiLCIiLCJhMXdBRDVxdzQ1UkVzNUZ3NGVSUVIzM3dxZTRXRSJd)

#### Explanation

```
    XI  Built-in regex matching integers
   @    Find all matches in
  a     Command-line input
$+      Fold on addition
```

Answer (score 1):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) -R, 31 bytes

```
[splits("\\D")|tonumber?]|0+add
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcSxDsIgEADQ/T6jk40xgZRzNSTgXhYG63AGhhotxaNh6beL8Q3vmVu78fqaCx@6aTJdv5e0bO9H/FzuuzhSCK0RCECQAkhokCRB/lOBePT2jMSaMWjC4A2QrNpgrgqdZbxWFd3ohqHmqLz9prXMaeF2cj8)

Answer (score 1):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com) + `regex`, 21 bytes

```
1#.0,'\d+'".&>@rxall]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FN1Zz8xBT1otT01Ap1LiU99TQFWysFdQUdBQMFKyDW1VNwDvJxW1pakqZrsdVQWc9ARz0mRVtdSU_NzqGoIjEnJxYid3OOJldqcka-QpqCeqI6nGmAYJoimIZIwokGjkgSiYZIHBSeSUpicWC4q5lpYrFjsWmKY6JpSrgLkjGG5Y4upoXlJqZBrsWmbuUmqUGBQcbG5YWpJuGu6hA3LlgAoQE)

```
1#.0,'\d+'".&>@rxall]
     '\d+'     rxall]  NB. find all matches of /\d+/ in right arg ]
              @        NB. then execute the monadic verb...
          ".&>         NB. eval each boxed match and unbox result
   0,                  NB. prepend 0 in case of no match
1#.                    NB. sum integer array
```

If adding the script to the language isn't allowed, then that adds `14` bytes for a total of `35`.

```
1#.0,'\d+'".&>@rxall(load'regex')]]
```

The only difference is the fork `(load'regex')]]` that loads the library and simply returns the function arg using dyadic `]`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), <s>19</s> 12 [bytes](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=U0JDUyDihpAgK0BcMOKKlwpEZWNvZGUg4oaQIOKHjOKKjy0x4pa9wrEu4o2Y4ouv4oav4oqCwq8x4qe74ouv4qe7LOKHjOKItSjihpjCrzHii68rMjU2KSAtQFwwKzEKJnAg4oqCIjggYml0IGVuY29kaW5nOlx0IiBTQkNTICLih4ziio8tMeKWvcKxLuKNmOKLr-KGr-KKgsKvMeKnu-KLr-Knuyzih4ziiLUo4oaYwq8x4ouvKzI1NikiIOKKgitAXDDih6ExMjkiLiziiLY74oiYwqzCscKv4oy14oia4peL4oyK4oyI4oGFPeKJoDziiaQ-4omlKy3Dl8O34pe_4oG_4oKZ4oan4oal4oig4qe74paz4oeh4oqi4oeM4pmt4ouv4o2J4o2P4o2W4oqa4oqb4oqd4pah4oqU4omF4oqf4oqC4oqP4oqh4oav4oaZ4oaY4oa74per4pa94oyV4oiK4oqXL-KIp1xc4oi14omh4oi64oqe4oqg4o2l4oqV4oqc4oip4oqT4oqD4oqZ4ouF4o2Y4o2c4o2a4qyaJz_ijaPijaQh4o6L4oas4pqCzrfPgM-E4oiefl9bXXt9KCnCr0AkXCLihpB8IyIKJnAg4oqCImRlY29kZWQ6XHQiIERlY29kZSAiwqPCsS0xwrjChy7DjMKlwrPCsMKIMcKfwqXCnyzCo8K_KMK1wogxwqUrMjU2KSIg4oqCK0BcMOKHoTEyOSIuLOKItjviiJjCrMKxwq_ijLXiiJril4vijIrijIjigYU94omgPOKJpD7iiaUrLcOXw7fil7_igb_igpnihqfihqXiiKDip7vilrPih6HiiqLih4zima3ii6_ijYnijY_ijZbiipriipviip3ilqHiipTiiYXiip_iioLiio_iiqHihq_ihpnihpjihrvil6vilr3ijJXiiIriipcv4oinXFziiLXiiaHiiLriip7iiqDijaXiipXiipziiKniipPiioPiipnii4XijZjijZzijZrirJonP-KNo-KNpCHijovihqzimoLOt8-Az4TiiJ5-X1tde30oKcKvQCRcIuKGkHwjIg==)

```
/+⊜parse≤@9.
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=ZiDihpAgLyviipxwYXJzZeKJpEA5LgoKZiAiYSIKZiAiMCIKZiAiNSIKZiAiMTAiCmYgImEwQSIKZiAiMWExIgpmICIxMWExIgpmICI0ZGFzUVdFNjVhc0FzNWRBYTVkV0QiCmYgImExd0FENXF3NDVSRXM1Rnc0ZVJRUjMzd3FlNFdFIg==)

-7 thanks to Bubbler

```
/+⊜parse≤@9.
           .  # duplicate
        ≤@9   # where are the characters less than or equal to 9?
  ⊜parse      # partition to an array of integers
/+            # sum
```

Comment: `⊜ partition` is the perfect built-in here, so `/+⊜parse≤@9.` works for 12. `≤@9` works because there are no letters below digits.

Comment: @Bubbler Nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
á¡O
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8MJDC/3//080LHd0MS0sNzENci02dSs3SQ0KDDI2Li9MNQl3BQA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfaXL/8MLDy30/6/zP1opUUlHyQCITYHYEMRINHAEMRMNQSSEMklJLA4MdzUzTSx2LDZNcUw0TQl3ASk1LHd0MS0sNzENci02dSs3SQ0KDDI2Li9MNQl3VYoFAA).

In [the new version of 05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands) it would have been 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) longer, because `¡` now supports substrings to split on (in the legacy version a string argument would be interpret as a list of characters implicitly) and will keep empty strings:

```
áS¡þO
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8MLgQwsP7/P//z/RsNzRxbSw3MQ0yLXY1K3cJDUoMMjYuLww1STcFQA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfaXL/8MLgw8tPLzP/7/O/2ilRCUdJQMgNgViQxAj0cARxEw0BJEQyiQlsTgw3NXMNLHYsdg0xTHRNCXcBaTUsNzRxbSw3MQ0yLXY1K3cJDUoMMjYuLww1STcVSkWAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
       # Example input: "a1wAD5qw45REs5Fw4eRQR33wqe4WE"

       # (legacy version)
á      # Only keep the letters of the (implicit) input-string
       #  STACK: "awADqwREsFweRQRwqeWE"
 ¡     # Split the (implicit) input-string on those characters
       #  STACK: ["1","5","45","5","4","33","4"]
  O    # Sum the remaining numbers
       #  STACK: 97
       # (which is output implicitly as result)

       # (new version)
á      # (same as above)
 S     # Split it to a list of characters
       #  STACK: ["a","w","A","D","q","w","R","E","s","F","w","e","R","Q","R","w","q","e","W","E"]
  ¡    # Split the (implicit) input-string on those characters
       #  STACK: ["","1","","","5","","45","","","5","","4","","","","33","","","4","",""]
   þ   # Remove all empty strings, by only keeping numbers
       #  STACK: ["1","5","45","5","4","33","4"]
    O  # (same as above)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [q](https://code.kx.com/home/), <s>41</s> 20 bytes

```
sum value .Q.n .Q.n?
```

## k, <s>23</s> 14 bytes

```
+/. .Q.n .Q.n?
```