# Remove each integer from a string and multiply them all!

Tags: code-golf, string, integer

## Goal:

- Get every integer from the string (not a number, but integer)
- Multiply them
- Output the result

## Input:

*5 kilograms of food eaten, 10 liters of water drank, 20 plates dirty, 40 mugs dirty, and only 3 people acted!*

## Output:

*120000*

## How:

*Result was 5 * 10 * 20 * 40 * 3*

## What do we count as an integer:

## General:

- If integer has a symbol BEFORE of AFTER the int, only take the number without symbols. `-335 or 335+` are 335 anyways.
- If integer has a symbol like this: `35:3`, don't take it. `35 : 3` is available though, and considered as 2 integers.

  ## Detailed:
- 35/3 aren't two integers, skip this
- 35.3 is not an integer, skip this
- 35:3, 35*3, 3e3, etc. aren't ints, skip them as well
- 353 is an integer
- 35 3 are two integers
- 353. is an integer
- 353?, 353!, etc. are integers
- -353 is an integer, but you only claim 353 and skip "-".
- +353 is the same case as upper

  ## Requirements:
- Select any language you want
- The program should contain as little bytes as possible
- You should tell us the language (if it's, like, exotic, link it like [this](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/ecndpcaalrlp))
- Please, upload the code to Try It Online services like [this](https://tio.run/##RY5NTsMwEEbX9Sk@lU0rQcQ@VfccgAOY8ZAMdcaWPRZEiLMHB4HYPr3vh3J@mIi27U6UYguMS7UgaZiv7h9JqlbYL1fXqugE9QvX7InR5dGJGhYvejrj0x0oNcPlgtPxySAVrXKAJbww3lo1eAV/@CVHHvBcGdbXStN7UBS6ob6L0YzodWp@4tr5nNLuzYykjDU1KHP4C@To173fuJfLK8RAackS@yylUpgsruOvvJfQ3L/2GwET2w@JorfheN5fs4Y4ukNha0XxOLqvbfsG)
- Count the bytes using special services like [this](https://www.charactercountonline.com/)
- It would be fine if you'd explain your code!

## Scoring:

Less bytes program wins! The end is 20th of June, you guys have a week

Comment: Can there be negative or zero integers? Can they have scientific notation?

Comment: Can there be numbers like `3.45` (which we should then discard)?

Comment: Can the string contain things like `13/06/2020`? In general, you should specify exactly what counts as an integer to be extracted and what doesn't

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109299/discussion-between-kviiten-and-luis-mendo).

Comment: They multiply ints by another int. Me - ints by unknown yet ints. Example: They got a sentence `3g 43` and number `2`. Their output was `6g 86` as soon as `3*2 and 43*2`. For me it would be `129` because of `3*43` @manatwork

Comment: I'm still not clear exactly what's an integer. You have lots of examples which is good, but need a rule.

Comment: General: If integer has a symbol BEFORE of AFTER the int, only take the number without symbols. If integer has a symbol like this: `35:3`, don't take it. `35 : 3` is available though, and considered as 2 integers.

Comment: I think this is an 1-character-change (in the submissions, `+` -> `*`) away from https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/181060/sum-integers-in-a-string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sum integers in a string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/181060/sum-integers-in-a-string)

Comment: It's definitely a near-dupe (of both that and [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/730/sum-of-integers-in-string-separated-by-non-numericals-such-as-a-and-y/205888#205888)), but even ignoring the strange and ambiguous rules about which integers to discard, the possible presence of 0 in a product could disrupt some answers. It's not a huge difference, though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## perl -pl, 64 bytes

```
s!\D+|\d+(?:[.:^e/]\d+)+|(\d+)!$1?"*".(0+$1):""!aeg;$_=eval"1$_"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nY1BTsMwEEX3nGJiZZESE9sJBhqEsuEWFCoLT6Oorm05BlSpZ8cYhKKuuxr9P3rvewxGpjQXm@f6tNF1NfQvTf@G7DWHVX2qfk9RioFck6bidSlWPSGFwvGx3D7hpzJElFuSkoT9ZNwY1GEGt4OdcxpQRbQUBAczRQx/j6/cBdBB2T2FloM3uZhBTyEeKdxyOHyMS1RWg7PmCB14dN4gqPeIurjKa@OZ@My0OOgC0ewAsWZcspbz9h/mF9JdI@GuyNtDFki8xwe2hq5h387Hydk53XjzAw)

Ignores anything which isn't a digit, or multiple sequences of digits separated by `/`, `.`, `e`, `:`, or `^`. Sequences of digits are replaced by themselves, prepended with *. The result, we eval, after predending 1. There's a tiny bit of hackery going to deal with numbers starting with 0s -- we don't want them be interpreted as octal numbers.

Reads lines from `STDIN`, writes the result to `STDOUT`.

Comment: The shortest won

Answer (score 4):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 109 bytes

```
func[s][p: 1 d: charset"0123456789"parse s[any[to d copy t[any d ahead[" "|"!"|"?"]](p: p * to p t)| skip]]p]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rY29bsMwDAb3PMVnTW3hwc5P03rJO3QVNAgmlRhWJEJSUBjIu7tKh3br1IHDHQleYlo/mLTZuAGru4VRZ6NlQA8aMF5sylxU1293@8Pr8e1dycMgaxsWXSIIY5QF5cEV7IUtaQV1V02dkzLmqT4TvKAeC8rzHXmexBgxq6QpFDioA@bJx3Oy14zo4GIksC0cWvQd/FQ4fS8@q0ugZMPcYttBfBUZNKWytNh3uN7OP2gDIQa/YAfhKJ5hx8LUqM1v9/RHt/nv7voF)

Comment: The challenge says that `353?`, `353!`, and `353.` are integers.

Comment: @Abigail Thank you, I've missed that part. I'll fix it

Comment: Don't answer duplicate/unclear questions.